# React hook form with redux and async request

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hook-form

Im using [React Hook Form](https://react-hook-form.com/) with redux.

In a component, I first have to perform an action that sends a request to the backend and assigns the result in Redux.

So in the component I don't have the value of the form at the beginning. Only when the data has been assigned in the Redux.

How can I now fill the fields with the values from the Redux?

```
export default function Foo() {
  const { baz } = useSelector(state => state.bar)

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchBaz())
  }

  const { handleSubmit, register, errors, reset, watch, setError } = useForm({
         validationSchema,
         defaultValues: baz
  })

  return (
    <input
      key="someKey"
      name={bazBaz}
      ref={register}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
  )
}
```

The problem is that when rendering for the first time, baz is not yet available and the defaultValues only set {}.

I found this[Async request with hook form](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/master/examples/asyncSetFormValues.tsx), but baz is not yet set in the promise and therefore I cannot do a `reset(baz)` there.

How do I set the fields in the form with existing values?

Comment: `useEffect(() => reset(baz), [baz, reset])`?

Comment: @Bill thanks, is not nice but it works. I have to make sure, that the fetchBaz i running only once. (Create an Answer, if you want)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resetting the form when you get new data inside a useEffect will do the Job. The code below is not tested, but you should get the idea.

```
export default function Foo() {
  const { baz } = useSelector(state => state.bar)

  const { handleSubmit, register, errors, reset, watch, setError } = useForm({
      defaultValues: baz
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchBaz())
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if(baz) reset(baz)
  }, [baz])


  return (
    <input
      name={'baz'}
      ref={register({})} 
    />
  )
}
```